# i accidently changed the feature of my left shift key now i cant use it

Tags: keyboard

how do I change it back? I cant type normally any more. 
I just installed Linux and was trying to make a short cut for something then it said this will removed the current function of said key. now I don’t know how to change it back

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**PART 1**

This will reset your keyboard. First of all go to http://pastebin.com/knERsenF chose your language.

Open please the Terminal and type

```
setxkbmap ch
```

replace ch with your countrycode from the pastebin.

**PART 2**

Attention, this will reset all your key bindings!!!!
Open Terminal and type the following commands (i dont remember if you need sudo, try it first without)

```
gsettings reset-recursively org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys
gsettings reset-recursively org.compiz.integrated
gsettings reset-recursively org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings
gsettings reset-recursively org.gnome.shell.keybindings
```

After this to Part 1 again

Comment: @Fabby thanks :-) , maybe i have to mention nexttime to backup current keyboard maping. But as he said he accidentaly deleted/changed the key im sure thats the correct method.

Comment: i had hopes that it would work but it didnt any more advie

Comment: please give part 2 a try.... an respond if this still does not help

Comment: still nothing..

Comment: Maybe a very stupid question, but can you please switch the keyboard to another usb port? You may ask why, thats because the keyboard should get re-initialized, as of now i think its possible that there is something else preventing it from working. Please switch the keyboard to another port while UBUNTU is running